# What's too much SQL Server data and how do I analyze my execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a relation between two tables with 600K rows and my first question is, is that a lot of data? It doesn't seem like a lot (in terms of rows, not bytes)

I can write a query like this

```
SELECT EntityID, COUNT(*)
FROM QueryMembership
GROUP BY EntityID
```

And it completes in now time at all, but when I do this.

```
SELECT EntityID, COUNT(*)
FROM QueryMembership
WHERE PersonID IN (SELECT PersonID FROM GetAcess(1))
GROUP BY EntityID
```

The thing takes 3-4 seconds to complete, despite just returning about 183 rows. `SELECT * FROM QueryMembership` takes about 12-13 seconds.

What I don't understand is how a filter like this would take so long, as soon as I introduce this table value function. The function it self doesn't take any time at all to return it's result and no matter if I write it as a CTE or some bizarre sub query the result is the same.

However, if it defer the filter, by inserting the result of the first select into a temporary table `#temp` then using the `GetAccess` UDF the entire thing goes about three times as fast.

I would really like some in-depth technical help on this matter. Where I should start look, and how I can analyze the execution plan to figure out what's going on.

Comment: No, 600K rows is not a lot. It's very common in enterprise apps to have millions of rows.

Comment: talk about 600 million rows - yes, then you start to get into "much data" ....

Comment: that's what I thought, good to at least have some estimate to go on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent series of posts on execution plans and how to read and interpret them - and a totally free e-book on the topic as well! - on the excellent Simple-Talk site.

Check them out - well worth the time!

- [Execution Plan Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)
- [SQL Server Execution Plans](http://www.simple-talk.com/books/sql-books/sql-server-execution-plans/)
- [Understanding More Complex Query Plans](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/understanding-more-complex-query-plans/)
- [Graphical Execution Plans for Simple SQL Queries](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/graphical-execution-plans-for-simple-sql-queries/)
- [SQL Server Execution Plans - free e-book download](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/sql-server-execution-plans---ebook-download/)

Answer (score 1):

600k rows is not a particularly large amount.  However, you are getting to the point where server configuration (disks, non-SQL load, etc) matters, so if your server wasn't carefully put together you should look at that now rather than later.

Analyzing execution plans is one of those things that you tend to pick up over time.  The book "Inside SQL Server" is (was?) pretty nice for learning how things work internally, which helps guide you a bit as you're optimzing.

I would personally try rewriting the above query as a join, IN often doesn't perform as well as you might hope.  Something like:

```
SELECT 
  EntityID, 
  COUNT(*)
FROM 
  QueryMembership q
  join GetAccess(1) a on a.PersonID = q.PersonID
GROUP BY 
  EntityID
```

Comment: Unfortunately and surprisingly so the JOIN is just as slow as everything else. The only thing which is faster is the temporary table approach and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EntityID, COUNT(*)
FROM QueryMembership
WHERE PersonID IN (SELECT PersonID FROM GetAcess(1))
GROUP BY EntityID
```

The embedded subquery is expensive. as you said using a temporary table is perfect alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reasons for your slowdown may be similar to those in this quesiton:

[how to structure an index for group by in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673235/how-to-structure-an-index-for-group-by-in-sql-server/1783690#1783690)

An execution plan will answer the question as to why the second query is slower, however I suspect it will be because SQL server can use indexes to look up aggregate functions (such as `COUNT` and `MAX`) using relatively inexpensive operations on some index.

If you combine a filter and a group however, SQL server can no longer use this trick and is forced to evaluate the value of `COUNT` or `MAX` based on the filtered result set, leading to expensive lookups.

600k rows is a fairly reasonable / small table size, however its big enough so that things like table scans or RDI lookups against large portions of the table will start becoming expensive.

I'd be interested to see the execution plan to understand whats going on.